# The wpf controls dose't displaying on the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I inheritance from a canvas control and I create my custom canvas class like this:

```
public class MyCanvas:Canvas
{
    //this list will contains all shape
    VisualCollection graphicsList;
    List<GraphicsBase> cloneGraphicsList;
    int c = 0;
    double deltaX = 0;
    double deltaY = 0;
    public MyCanvas()
        :base()
    {
        graphicsList = new VisualCollection(this);
        cloneGraphicsList = new List<GraphicsBase>();
    }

   public VisualCollection GraphicsList
    {
        get
        {
            return graphicsList;
        }
        set
        {
            graphicsList = value;
        }
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return graphicsList.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= graphicsList.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
        }
        return graphicsList[index];
    }
    public GraphicsBase this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= 0 && index < GraphicsList.Count)
            {
                return (GraphicsBase)GraphicsList[index];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return GraphicsList.Count;
        }
    }
 }
```

and in XAML use this code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:CustomCanvas="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
xmlns:WPFRuler="clr-namespace:Orbifold.WPFRuler;assembly=Orbifold.WPFRuler"
Title="PrintVarsDesigner" Height="709" Width="964"
Background="LightGray" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="False" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" 
WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
  <CustomCanvas:MyCanvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Width="895" Height="1162">
  </CustomCanvas:MyCanvas>
</Window>
```

the controls does't appear after add its from visual screen or C# code by add child to canvas.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheriting WPF controls is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226281/wpf-control-inheritance) to say the least. WPF control's are "lookless". that is to say, the control itself doesn't know how it's going to be presented. When the control is placed in a window WPF looks for the corresponding `ControlTemplate` to this specific control.

The problem with inherited controls is that they have no such template. If you want to display it, you'll have to write one yourself, and that's not always simple. You can find an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575645/Inheriting-from-a-Look-Less-WPF-Control), but i'd recommend against it. Use [UserControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) [instead](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W).

Comment: A great response and references. Thank you!