# uwp should I be using user control inside a data template?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, uwp, datatemplate

in my UWP app I was thinking to extract my data template into a seperate user control , i.e: `<DataTemplate><local:CustomTemplate/></DataTemplate>`
and the user control ( customtemplate ) will have that stackpanel or grid which was previously in my DataTemplate directly, along with its bindings, I already know how to achieve this.

**My Question** is that by extracting out the data template in a user control, would this cause any performance hit? I read somewhere that while doing this each **GridViewItem** proceeds to execution of **InitializeComponent()** of the user control is executed and xaml is parsed on UI, which causes performance issues? But if we keep the data Template within same file ( not extracted in a user control ) then no performance issue will occurs. **is this true ?**

Comment: Why not simply give it a try, and see if it in any way impacts the performance of your application?

Comment: Do you need a code-behind class or a custom view model for the content of the dataTemplate? Otherwise, I see no point in creating the user control.

Comment: @NahuelIanni I am using ViewModel and binding ItemSource of the grdiview to an ObservableCollection property of the ViewModel. I will be using that same data template on multiple pages that is why I wanted to extract it into a user control

Comment: @Clemens my pc doesnt have much files to test scenarios with high number of files, bcz when files are low, any performance change will be undetectable

Comment: So you want to deliver the app without testing it with many files? That sounds like a bad idea. If you expect it to work with a large amount of data on the customer's side, you should test that before delivery.

Comment: You can still create a data template shared across views as a resource

Comment: @NahuelIanni actually my data template has x:Bind so it needs code behind file as well. how can I share that accross the resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if you purely want to use the same `DataTemplate` that uses `x:Bind` across different components, you don't have to wrap all your elements in either a *UserControl* or *Custom Control*.

You just need to create a resource dictionary called `Templates.xaml` that includes all the data templates (with `x:Bind`!) you want to share, as well as a `cs` class with the same name like this -

```
public partial class Templates  
{
    public Templates()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then in your `Templates` resource dictionary, add a `x:Class` attribute to point to the class you just created -

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="xxx.Templates" ..>
```

Finally you will need to merge this resource dictionary into your `App.xaml` or a parent resource dictionary -

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
    <local:Templates />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Now build and run and it should work. Please refer to Igor's excellent [post](http://igrali.com/2015/06/14/how-to-use-compiled-bindings-xbind-from-a-resource-dictionary/) on this topic that I followed a couple of years ago which has worked for me flawlessly. I was even able to create code-behind stuff in there too.

---

Now back to your original question, would using a `UserControl` be bad for performance?

I personally believe the answer is **NO** in UWP.

Historically in WPF, using a *UserControl* inside a virtualized items control calls the `InitializeComponent()` inside the `UserControl` every time a new data template is created, which leads to performance issues so people tend to use a *Custom Control* instead.

However, this is no longer the case in UWP, where no matter it's a *UserControl*, *Custom Control* or even just a `Grid`, as long as they have the same exact child elements, they will be loaded the same amount of times. This means that the `InitializeComponent` inside the *UserControl* will only be called a small number of times until the virtualized `ListView` has enough numbers to recycle through the whole list.

But keep in mind that another control wrapper is an additional layer, it will always suck a little bit more memory. So unless you want additional logic on your template such as having dependency properties to show/hide stuff, you don't have to extract its content to put into another *UserControl* or *Custom Control*.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Avalue of type Templates could not be added to a dictionary of type IList. This is the error visual studio is giving me. when I try to merge it into App.xaml as you mentioned

Comment: also I want to use 2 things within my data templates.
 1. Visual State Manager.
 2. Handle Events in code behind ( by accessing the Name properties of the  elements.

Can I achieve these 2 if I use a data template in resource dictionary? or should I make a user control of data template to achieve these 2 ?

Comment: Try to follow the blog post in details. You must have missed something. Data templates can give you no. 2. If you want adaptive triggers in your VSM, you will have to create a UserControl.

Comment: also if I make a user control, can I use it to make another user control?

Comment: You mean one UserControl that wraps another? Absolutely.

Comment: I am able to succesfuly extract data template out in resource dictionary and it works fine, But I can access any Named elements in code behind in Templates.cs class , and also InitializeComponent() . can you please guide me how to do code behind? I want to access elements which are within the data template

Comment: You need to access them in the `Loaded` event, like how you normally create a `Loaded` event handler on a page.