# Templated Control vs Custom Control in UWP. No clear answer found online

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, uwp

In my UWP app, my control options are User Control and Templated Control. My understanding of a User Control is KIND OF clear at this point.

I was told that a Custom Control's style/template is only instantiated in memory once, and that this only happens at the time the control is first used. That's what I want since I know the control I am creating will be used in a ListView.

In the book, XAML Unleashed, however, the author creates his Custom Control by starting with a User Control, and then simply changing it's base class. The thing is that the control he created calls `InitializeComponent()`. I hear that this type of class uses more memory because it is re-instatiated for each item in the ListView.

Also, I never thought that Custom Controls used the `InitializeComponent()` method. I thought there was simply a call to `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyClass);` in the constructor. What gives? I am confused on what is what...

And last, why is the style/template of the Templated Control placed in the global Generic.xaml file, instead of its own separate file (i.e., xaml file and a code-behind file pair)? If the control is supposed to be custom and "portable", then shouldn't it be totally separate from other code? I haven't found a single article explains any of these things in detail on any level.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334512/when-to-use-a-templated-control-over-a-usercontrol/29339295#29339295

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131106/wpf-controltemplate-vs-usercontrol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is something most people get wrong so I'll try to clarify a few things for you.

**Memory**

The whole memory thing, it's all in the Visual Tree. When you instantiate any control, whether templated or `UserControl`, you will use up memory with every instance because in both cases you are creating a full copy of the visual components in the template.

The templated control will create a copy from the `ControlTemplate` while the `UserControl` parses the XAML file when `InitializeComponent()` is called.

Memory usage will be the same if you create 100 templated controls or 100 user controls if their content is the same.

**Usage**

Templated controls are best for situations where you're creating a single component, like a `Button`, `Slider`, `MyStarRatingInput`, etc. and you're giving the users of your control the ability to swap out the template with their own. It takes a lot more effort to do this properly than `UserControls` because the logic has to be template agnostic and your templates have to react properly with visual state changes.

A `UserControl` is best for layout or views, like forms, popups, screens, pages, etc. You will not give someone the freedom to tamper with the content of your view. You may expose a few public/dependency properties if some views are reusable in a small way, but generally they are set in stone.

**Generic.xaml**

I honestly don't have an answer for this. Microsoft should've allowed multiple resource dictionaries to enable cleaner partitioning of control templates. `Generic.xaml` is a reserved filename that referencing projects will look for as the root source of the base styles of your controls. You could reference other XAML files from `Generic.xaml`, but that's annoying and it bloats the root of your resource dictionary. For now, you're stuck with this method.

**Recommendation**

If you're sharing a control library, you would want to use templated controls as much as possible. If you're building controls, views, pages, etc for your current project and they're not meant for reuse, then use `UserControls`.

You can still create a `UserControl` in your control library if you plan on owning the template and forcing all users to accept your design.

I also recommend templated controls for items that you plan on instantiating a hundred times in a single view, like a `ListView`. You will see noticeable speed improvement if your template is preloaded into memory instead of parsing a XAML file on every instance.

Comment: Added an answer for generic.xaml

Comment: FYI, you can point your `generic.xaml` to other Resource Dictionaries to separate templates per control, we do this in the Windows Community Toolkit here: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Themes/Generic.xaml